# Correlation of the min and max of random numbers in $(0,1)$

Tags: probability, covariance, correlation

Generate three random numbers independently and uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$. Let $X$ be the smallest of these three numbers and $Y$ the biggest.

(a)  Do you expect $X$ and $Y$ are positively correlated, negatively correlated, or uncorrelated? Explain your reasoning intuitively then find the value of the correlation coefficient $\rho(X,Y)$.

(b)  Suppose $n$ (as opposed to three) random numbers are generated. Compute the correlation coefficient $\rho(X,Y)$.

Answer: Am I correct in assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated because they are independent, and thus $\rho(X,Y)$ is 0 in both cases?

Comment: I edited the title of your question to reflect what is in the question body and also moved the set-up into the question itself, instead of the title. Please feel free to edit the title if you feel like it doesn't fit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I correct in assuming that X and Y are uncorrelated because they are independent,

Totally wrong!

Define $U,V$ two independend rv's form Uniform distribution in $[0;1]$

$X$ and $Y$ are not independent but positively correlated. In fact the value of $Y=max(U,V)$ depends on the values of $X$.

If, as an example $X=0.7$ the values of Y are not anymore in $[0;1]$ but greater than 0.7.

**Easy example**: just as an hint, suppose we generate only 2 random numbers independently, say $U,V$.

Set $X=min(U;V)$ and $Y=max(U;V)$

The correlation between $X$ and $Y$ can be misured with their covariance

$$Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)=E(UV)-E(X)E(Y)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{36}$$

---

skipping for a moment case a), for the general case b), after some calculations based on [Order Statistics](http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ehchen/teaching/LargeSample/notes/noteorder.pdf), the covariance results to me

$$Cov(X;Y)=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}$$

Which, for $n=2$ results exactly $\frac{1}{36}$ as derived before and $\frac{1}{80}$ for case a), when $n=3$

This means, as intuitive it is, that the greater is $n$ the lower is the linear dependence between Max and min.

If you want,as requested, you can easy calculate also $\rho(X,Y)$ but covariance is enough to capture linear dependence between the rv's

---

How to derive the general solution (sketch)

---

By definition,

$$Cov(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$$

$\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ are very easy to calculate using the distribution of min and max, obtaining respectively $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $\frac{n}{n+1}$

The hardest probelm is to calculate $\mathbb{E}[XY]$. To solve it I used the definition of density of order statistics that you can find in the link above.

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=n(n-1)(y-x)^{n-2}$$

where $x<y$

Thus

$$\mathbb{E}[XY]=\int_0^1 n xdx\Bigg[\int_x^1 (n-1)y(y-x)^{n-2}dy    \Bigg]dx=\dots=\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

When solving the integral, you will arrive at the following

$$\mathbb{E}[XY]=n\int_0^1 x(1-x)^{n-1}dx-\int_0^1 x(1-x)^{n}dx=n\frac{\Gamma(2)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n+2)}-\frac{\Gamma(2)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+3)}=$$

$$=\frac{n(n-1)!}{(n+1)!}-\frac{n!}{(n+2)!}=\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)}$$

This results follow using [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

Comment: Can you explain how you derived that?

Comment: @Tyson2 : Added the complete procedure.

Comment: Are you the guy from slader?

Comment: @Tyson2 ; No. Did you understand the answer? Since you're new here, I would like to encourage you to click the check mark if this answer was helpful for you. It'll encourage others to answer your questions in the future

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaking the independence of the three random numbers, call them $A, B, C$ for the independence (whether or not they actually are independent) of the minimum $X = \min(A,B,C)$ and maximum $Y = \max(A, B, C)$. As you can see, $X$ and $Y$ are both functions of $A, B, C$, so it is not immediate that they would be independent of each other.

To start building your intuition, if I tell you that $Y = 1/2$, then does that give you any information about $X$? Does that suggest anything about the correlation of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Yes, I see now. $Y = 1/2$ means $X < 1/2$